# How to use Finger Print sensor?

Tags: package-management, hardware, fingerprint-reader

i am using ubuntu 11.10 on my aspire 5237g i am having finger print reader in built with touch-pad. i am not able to use that . if someone provide me package details and installation procedure . 
i am posting result of  **`lsusb`** cmd

[image: Output of lsusb]

Can anyone Suggest me what i have to do for using finger print sensor in ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fingerprint authentication for Ubuntu based on fprintd

Add this PPA to your sources:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint`

Update your package list and system

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Install the software:

`sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd gksu-polkit`

[source](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint)