# Finger print driver for Dell Vostro 3460

Tags: drivers, authentication, fingerprint-reader, dell-vostro

Where do i get the driver for finger print recognition for Dell Vostro 3460 and how can I use my fingerprint reader for login?

Fingerprint Reader: Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader (USB-id: 138a:0011)

Comment: You could try checking this tutorial out: http://www.tuxtrix.com/2012/05/how-to-activate-validity-fingerprint.html Your model isn't listed but it seems pretty close to the ones mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Finger Print sensor?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81073/how-to-use-finger-print-sensor)

Comment: @TomBrossman The answer for that question directs to ppa:fingerprint/fprint which doesn't support this laptop's fingerprint device (138a:0011). So it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @EricCarvalho I think the question is a duplicate but the answer there needs to be edited and added to. If we have separate questions for every possible fingerprint reader it'll get too fragmented. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a HP Pavilion laptop with Finger print reader from **Validity sensors, Inc**., But my model differs from yours (**VFS301**). A Reverse Engineering has been done by someone to make it work under Gnu/Linux

You can download the source code and compile to generate binary to check if this works for you. Take a look at the **README** file to get started.

[Get code here](https://github.com/PrasannaVenkadesh/vfs301)