# Something like driver package for Dell Vostro 3560?

Tags: drivers, dell, dell-vostro

I recently got My Dell Vostro 3560, and installed Ubuntu 13.04.

Since then I reinstalled in multiple times (Unity gone for Graphic driver problems), had to setup some ACPI stuff to get the fan under controll and installed ever more stuff to make the brigthness changing work. I still cannot use the dedicated graphic card, cannot use that "cache to ssd" mechanism used on Win7, cannot make palm controll of the touchpad work, left alone disabling the touchpad, cannot make my screen extend over to hdmi (just cloning, but than the upper 100 pixel are missing on the hd-ready TV), cannot set a reasonable DPI without rendering menues unusable, cannot make fingerprint sensors work, cannot stop battery being emptied in 50 minutes, multimedia buttons have no function, turboboost won't turn on (I am loosing 1.2GHz) and so on.

**So my question is: did I miss something fundamental to make that device run with ubuntu, like getting some driver packages?**

Is it simply not compatible with ubuntu, or did I get the wrong picture and it is normal that you never stop installing and start USING linux? I mean before I never had a single thought about what makes the screen brightnes controll work - I always simply assumed that an OS in 2013 is capable of this out of the box.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to everything, but my guess, from your message, is that you have not yet installed any of the "additional drivers" that your Vostro needs.  If this is the case and you don't already know how, do this:
 1. Start up the Software Updater.
 2. Click on "Settings". This will display a box with tabs.  The last tab should be called "Additional Drivers". Click that.
 3. At that point, you should see available proprietary drivers for both your ATI graphics card AND you Broadcom network card.  Go ahead and install them.

This should solve the display issues (as it does with my own Vostro 3560 running 13.04).

As to the fingerprint reader: unfortunately, the Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 fingerprint reader that you almost certainly have is not yet supported.  There is some news of a hack here: [Finger print driver for Dell Vostro 3460](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234556/finger-print-driver-for-dell-vostro-3460?rq=1), but it's not really there yet.

Comment: Installing aditional graphics drivers on a Dell Vostro 3560 can be very counterproductive if I remember correctly.